# Http request.getParameter( fieldname ) with List

Tags: java, html, httprequest

I see that if an entry form in html has an input type = text ...
I can read this text as a String with

```
request.getParameter( fieldname ).
```

But how can I read a List if the select is multiple?

I would like to set an ArrayList in a bean based on more than one parameter.
Like this

```
List<String> values = request.getParameter( fieldsList );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [getParameterValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29):

**getParameterValues**

> `String[]` `getParameterValues`(`String` name) Returns an `array` of String
>   objects containing all of the values the given request parameter has,
>   or null if the parameter does not exist. If the parameter has a single
>   value, the array has a length of 1.
>
> Parameters: name - a `String` containing the name of the parameter whose
>   value is requested Returns: an array of String objects containing the
>   parameter's values See Also: getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: My brains refuse to function? I can't see where I select my question to mark it as answered.

Comment: Yes I can see the check mark now. Got mind blurred by hours of refreshing Eclipse and Tomcat and wrestling with url pattern